# Building libraries using Premake5 without separate project files for each build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, premake

I have a large project and it takes quite a lot of time to compile the whole thing. A small change in a header file will result in building the whole project again even though it doesn't affect most of the other components. Is there a way to use premake5 to build source files in the project to its own library file (preferably .lib files) without creating separate projects for all of them?

Thank You!

Comment: You mean build the project as a static/dynamic library?

Comment: Nope. My project builds to a static lib file but since it has a lot of components, it takes a lot of time to compile the project even after a small edit. To tackle this, I want to create smaller static library files using the components in the project without having multiple project files just for that component. @SzymonO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Premake is designed to generate projects that can work with a variety of different toolsets, and most (no?) IDEs support that workflow.